# making bootstrap menubar of fix size

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I am trying to add dropdown submenu to bootstrap menubar, Submenu appears as soon as i hover on the "people aspect".But when submenu appears it is extending the size of menubar. Is there any way the fix the size of the menubar

Here is the code

```
<div class="navbar navbar-inverse navbar-fixed-top" >
        <div class="container" >
            <div class="navbar-header">
                <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target=".navbar-collapse">
                    <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                    <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                    <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                </button>
                <div >
                    @*  @Html.ActionLink("Application name", "Index", "Home", null, new { @class = "navbar-brand" })*@<img src="~/Images/InfosysLogo.png" style="height:70px;width:200px" />
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="navbar-collapse collapse">
                <ul id="nav" class="nav navbar-nav">
                    <li>@Html.ActionLink("DashBoard", "ExecutiveDashboard", "Charts")</li>
                    <li>@Html.ActionLink("Engagement Metrics", "EngagementMatrix", "Charts")</li>
                    <li>@Html.ActionLink("Quality Metrics", "Contact", "Home")</li>
                    <li>
                        @Html.ActionLink("People Aspects", "Contact", "Home")

                    <ul id="subnav">
                        <li>@Html.ActionLink("Certifications", "Index", "Certification", new { @class = "my-class" })</li>
                        <li>@Html.ActionLink("Trainings", "Index", "Training", new { @class = "my-class" })</li>
                    </ul>
                </li>
                <li>@Html.ActionLink("Financials", "BudgetVSActualChart", "Financial")</li>
                <li>@Html.ActionLink("Admin", "AdminView", "PMODashboard")</li>
            </ul>
                <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
                    <li class="navbar-text">Hello, @User.Identity.Name!</li>
                </ul>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="container body-content">
```

Any help will be appreciable.
Thank you

Comment: set width in px for the parent container

Answer (score 0, accepted):

example try this code of css and check

**HTML**

```
<div class="navbar navbar-inverse navbar-fixed-top" >

</div>
```

**CSS**

```
.navbar{
 width:980px;
}
```

Comment: Maybe you will need to add ``!important`` at the end of your ``width`` property.

Comment: @vas  if i am fixing the width of menubar then the menu items are getting lost if i am reducing the size of the window

Comment: Maybe ``max-width: 980px;`` ?

Comment: @vas actually i needed to set my height not the width     
accept
HTML

<div class="navbar navbar-inverse navbar-fixed-top" >

</div>
CSS

.navbar{
 min-height:90px !important;
}                                                          Thankyou for your help anyway

Answer (score 0):

**HTML**

```
<div class="navbar navbar-inverse navbar-fixed-top" >

</div>
```

**CSS**

```
.navbar{
 min-height:90px !important;
}
```

resolved my issue it set the min height to 90px so when i was hovering on menu item submenu items were not extending my menubar